# Проблема с наследованием и методами

Tags: java, наследование, методы

Есть класс `Animal` и сабкласс `Cat`, хочу, чтоб `Cat` принимал имя и ограничение на максимальное расстояние для бега.

Но созданный метод выводит всегда результат "бежит" при любом отрицательном параметре расстояния и "не может бежать" при любом положительном параметре. Не пойму, как исправить?

Класс **Animal**:

```
public class Animal {
    protected String name;
    protected boolean canRun = true;
    protected boolean canSwim = true;
    protected boolean canJump = true;
    protected int maxRunLength;
    protected double maxJumpHeigth;
    protected int maxSwimLength;
    protected int length;
    protected double jump;



    public Animal(){
    }

    public  Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run(int length) {
        if (length <= this.maxRunLength) {
            System.out.println(this.name + " is running");
        } else {
            System.out.println("can`t run");
        }
    }
}
```

Класс **Cat**:

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    protected int maxRunLength;
    protected double maxJumpHeigth = 2;
    protected boolean canSwim = false;

    public Cat(){
    }

    public Cat(String name, int maxRunLength) {
        this.name = name;
        this.maxRunLength = maxRunLength;
    }

}
```

Comment: А если написать this.length в операторе if, то бег будет происходить при любых параметрах...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не меняется переменная `length` у `Animal`, а если она не меняется, то результат условия `if (this.length <= this.maxRunLength)` тоже будет постоянным.

```
public void run(int length) {
    this.lenght += length;
    if (this.length <= this.maxRunLength) {
        System.out.println(this.name + " is running");
    } else {
        System.out.println("can`t run");
    }
}
```

А если вам и нужен постоянный результат при неизменном `length` (то есть просто хотите отсекать значения больше `maxRunLength`, то у вас еще `this.maxRunLength` не инициализирована, то есть всегда равна 0. Из-за этого и любое положительное отсекает, тк оно больше 0.

Comment: И правда, не подскажите, как его инициализировать, а то я думал, что сделал это...

Comment: @NarX8 можно передавать в конструкторе `public  Animal(String name, int maxRunLength) { this.maxRunLength = maxRunLength;
    this.name = name;
}` Советую так же сразу дописать все параметры туда, которые вам нужно инициализировать при создании `Animal`.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает для класса Animal, но в классе Cat выдает ту же ошибку (бежит при отрицательных значениях), видимо, я с наследованием или переменными что-то не допонял

Comment: Похоже разобрался, указал в Cat родительский конструктор через super и стало вроде правильно работать.